# Subgroups and Cosets Question

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I'm having trouble establishing this proof for my abstract algebra class. The question is

> Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $g$ is an element of $G$. Prove that the following subset of $G$ 
>   $$\left\{ ghg^{-1}|h\in H\right\}$$ (denoted $gHg^{-1}$) is a subgroup of $G$.

I'm not sure how to answer this question to satisfy that the subset is closed. I can prove that the inverse exists and therefore the identity exists by the following logic: $$(ghg^{-1})^{-1}=gh^{-1}g^{-1}$$ And therefore since $H$ is defined to be a subgroup then $h^{-1}\in H$ $$\therefore gh^{-1}g^{-1}\in \left\{ ghg^{-1}|h\in H\right\}$$ Hence the inverse exists. Therefore $ghg^{-1}gh^{-1}g^{-1}=e$ and the identity exists.

However I'm a little shaky on the proof for the subset is closed. My attempt goes like this:

Since $g$ is an element $\in G$ then it is constant, therefore only the value of $h$ is changing. So take two elements of the subset $ghg^{-1}$ and $gh'g^{-1}$. Compose them together giving: $$ghg^{-1}gh'g^{-1}=ghh'g^{-1}$$ Since $H$ is a subgroup then $hh'\in H$ $$\therefore ghh'g^{-1} \in\left\{ ghg^{-1}|h\in H\right\}$$

Would this proof hold to show that the subset of $G$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Thanks

Comment: Your proof looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely correct.

Comment: The proof is absolutely correct. But there are minor inaccuracies in what you wrote.

Comment: Where are the inaccuracies? So I can streamline the proof :)